# Bind rvalue reference to lvalue with `void*`

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, rvalue-reference, lvalue

While trying to understand how rvalue references work I ended up with this piece of code:

```
int* iptr = nullptr;
int*&& irr = iptr;
```

Compiling the above code gives the following error:

> error: rvalue reference to type 'int *' cannot bind to lvalue of type
>   'int *'

I understand this is correct, but why does the following code, where I bind using a `void*` instead of `int*`, compiles without any problem? Will the runtime behavior be correct or should I expect undefined behavior?

```
int* iptr = nullptr;
void*&& irr = iptr;
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is well-formed.

`int*` and `void*` are different types; you can't bind a `int*` to reference to `void*` directly. The `int*` needs to be converted to `void*` firstly, which is a temporary object and could be bound to rvalue-reference. (PS the lifetime of the temporary is extended to the lifetime of the reference.)

Note that `irr` doesn't bind to `iptr`; so any modification on it has nothing to do with `iptr`.

This is not special for `void*`, same thing happens for other types, e.g.

```
char c;
int&& r = c; // a temporary int is constructed from c and then bound to r;
             // its lifetime is extened to the lifetime of r
```

Answer (score 11):

In addition to @songyuanyao answer: you could make an rvalue out of `iptr` e.g. by means of `static_cast`:

```
  int* iptr = nullptr;
  int*&& irr = static_cast<int *>(iptr);
```

Comment: Why not just `std::move`?

Comment: @songyuanyao because a move would actually bind `irr` to `iptr`.

Comment: If you find the `static_cast` clunky, know that `int *&&irr = +iptr;` does the same thing :)

Comment: @Quentin Got it. Didn't think the conversion to same type also constructs a new temporary.

Comment: @songyuanyao consider that for a class type `Foo(anotherFoo)` and `static_cast<Foo>(anotherFoo)` are equivalent :)

Comment: @Quentin Yes I realised that. As you said, it's same as `+iptr` even one is explicit conversion the other is implicit conversion.

Comment: @Quentin could you expand your comment? what do you mean with actually bind? and what's the difference in those terms if I use the static_cast?

Comment: @Nick it means that `irr` refers to (gives access to) `iptr` itself. With the cast, `irr` refers to the unnamed result of the cast (whose lifetime is extended to live as long as `irr`), which is a copy of `iptr`.

Comment: @IgorR. [Yes it is](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime#Temporary_object_lifetime): "The lifetime of a temporary object may be extended by binding to a `const` lvalue reference or to an rvalue reference".

Comment: @Quentin You're right. It turns out that the lifespan of *prvalue* is extended in such a case - but not of an *xvalue*.